# Downcast gives ClassCastException

Tags: java, classcastexception, extends

Two classes:

```
public class ClassA implements ClassC {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1111111111111111111L;
    public String varA;
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA implements ClassC {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4604935970051141456L;
    public String varB;
}
```

In my code I have this declaration:
`ClassB classB;`

and a method

> myMethod()

that returns a `ClassA` object.

If I write:

```
classB = (ClassB) myMethod();
```

I thought that I will have:

```
classB.varA = <a value from myMethod()>
classB.varB = null
```

but this is not so: I receive a **ClassCastException**.

Why? And how can assign the `myMethod()` to `ClassB` in a fast way?

Comment: Show all the relevant code. I'm not sure I understand what you tried to do.

Comment: A cast will not change the class of an object, it merely verifies that the object is of that class (or some subclass of that class).  If your myMethod returned a ClassB object but typed it as ClassA then the cast would work.

Comment: I don't understand why class B implements class C, If class A implements class C and class B extends class A then doesn't class B also implicitly implement class C interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to downcast a `ClassA` to a `ClassB`, which isn't allowed because the actual object might be `ClassX` (another subclass of `ClassA`) which doesn't have an explicit conversion.

See the following example which will throw a `ClassCastException` (but compiles just fine):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubB var = (SubB) someMethod();         
    }

    private static Super someMethod(){
        return new SubA();
    }
}

class Super { }
class SubA extends Super { }
class SubB extends Super { }
```

The code compiles perfectly:

- `someMethod()` returns a class of type `Super`.
- `SubA` extends `Super` so the method definition isn't violated
- `SubB` extends `Super` so it can cast an object of type `Super` to `SubB`

Yet when you execute this, you'll try to cast an object of type `SubA` to `SubB`, which isn't possible.

Sidenotes:

- Don't use `ClassC` to name an `interface`
- Put hierarchy in your classnames for small examples here (Super <-> Sub) instead of (A <-> B <-> C)

Answer (score 1):

Casts in Java are not like dynamic_cast<...> of pointers in C++. With the latter, if the types are incompatible, the result is a null pointer. In Java, casting incompatible references results in `ClassCastException`.

The usual Java idiom is to test the reference beforehand using `instanceof` and then only performing the cast if the result is true. For example,

```
ClassA a = myMethod();
if (a instanceof ClassB) {
    ClassB b = (ClassB) a;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ClassA are not ClassB interchangable. Change your method to return `ClassC` (the interface), and store that reference as a `ClassC` and then you can use `ClassA` or `ClassB`. A is-a C and B is-a C, but A is-not a B even though B is-a A. If that helps.

Comment: Note that you can store a ClassB object in a reference typed as ClassA, and treat it as a ClassA.  If you want to then treat it as a ClassB you would use (ClassB) to obtain a reference typed as ClassB.

Comment: `B` extends `A`, so `ClassB` is-a `ClassA`. I have put what I believe to be the issue in an answer.